# R - type in multiple strings without quotation marks

Tags: string, r, stata

I need to type in a vector of strings. Each element is a variable name to be used in a later loop. It's a pain to type in all the quotation marks and commas -- is there a way to just type it like so (this is something I can do in Stata):

```
balance.vars <- c(a3 a4 a5_1 a5_2 a5_3 a6_1 a6_2 a6_3 a6_4
a6_5 a6_6 a8 a8_1 a8_2 a8_3 a9 a9_3
a10_1 a10_2 a10_3)
etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scan` with `text`:

```
balance.vars <- scan(text='a3 a4 a5_1 a5_2 a5_3 a6_1 a6_2 a6_3 a6_4
a6_5 a6_6 a8 a8_1 a8_2 a8_3 a9 a9_3
a10_1 a10_2 a10_3',what='char')
```

But I would avoid to use many separated variables like this. What not to use a vector or a list? Maybe ifyou explain better your workflow and what do you want to do we can propose more R-style solution.

You can also use `paste` to create such list, for example:

```
paste(paste0('a',rep(3:10,each=3)),rep(0:3,8),sep='_')
```

**EDIT** after OP clarification, it seems he wants to filter a data.frames variables.

```
 varnames  <- colnames(d)[grepl('^a[0-9]+(_[1-3])?',colnames(d))]
 formulas <- paste(varnames, "group", sep = " ~ ") 
 res <- lapply(formulas, function(f) t.test(as.formula(f), data = d))
```

Comment: I am just making a balance table -- essentially running t-tests on a bunch of variables. My solution requires a vector of of variable names:

Comment: varnames <- c("var1", "var2") # This is the one
formulas <- paste(varnames, "group", sep = " ~ ")
res <- lapply(formulas, function(f) t.test(as.formula(f), data = d))

Comment: Yes, but I need to select some, but not all, variables in the dataframe to run t-test on. Thus I cannot just exclude `group` and use the rest. The variable names also come from an existing survey, so I can't create nice variable name like you suggested. That's good practice though.

Comment: That's a good suggestion actually ... I'll definitely think about that.

Comment: The full list of variables is in my original question. So the pattern is pretty small like: a5_*, with * going from 1 to 3

Answer (score 2):

R doesn't support this style for function calls. But if you put all the variable names in a text file (one per line), like this:

```
a3
a4
a5_1
a6_1
etc.
```

You can then do:

```
balance.vars <- scan('varnames.txt', what='')
```

and not have to type all those quotation marks and commas.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
balance.vars <- unlist(strsplit("a3 a4 a5_1 a5_2 a5_3 a6_1 a6_2 a6_3 a6_4 a6_5 a6_6 a8 a8_1 a8_2 a8_3 a9 a9_3 a10_1 a10_2 a10_3", " "))
```

or:

```
balance.vars <- unlist(strsplit("a3 a4 a5_1 a5_2 a5_3
a6_1 a6_2 a6_3 a6_4 a6_5 a6_6 a8 a8_1 a8_2 a8_3 a9 a9_3
a10_1 a10_2 a10_3", "\\W", perl=TRUE))
```

if you want to use line breaks to improve readability. :-)

Comment: I should have thought of this! Basic string manipulation that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Using the qdap package:

```
library(qdap)

qcv(terms="a3 a4 a5_1 a5_2 a5_3 a6_1 a6_2 a6_3 a6_4
a6_5 a6_6 a8 a8_1 a8_2 a8_3 a9 a9_3
a10_1 a10_2 a10_3")
```